# BluetoothClass of devices - what is what?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I made an app that discovers Bluetooth devices around me, and I'm looking into the datas I get about them. Now I'm trying to figure out the datas from BluetoothDevice.getBluetoothClass (CoD, Class of Device).
So far I've found these class codes around me:

- 43c
- 50c
- 704
- 1f00
- c043c
- c243c
- 8043c
- 60680
- 200408
- 240414
- 5a020c

About half of these I found some information for (http://domoticx.com/bluetooth-class-of-device-lijst-cod/). The rest of the codes I haven't been able to find anywhere (50c, c043c, c243c, 60680).

Does anyone know any overview with all of these codes (or at least the ones I haven't figured out)?

Answer (score 4):

You can decode the Bluetooth Class of Device (CoD) yourself by first converting the above hex number to binary (for example using this [link](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-binary.html)) and then checking the document below to try and find what the combination of the bits mean:-

https://www.ampedrftech.com/datasheets/cod_definition.pdf

As an example, 0x50c is 010100001100 in binary. Using the table in the document above, bits 8 to 12 indicate that the device is a peripheral:

[image]

And then bits 2 to 5 indicate that the device is a remote control

[image]